# Facebook Page Plugin - Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: html, facebook, plugins, x-frame-options

So here is my website which i have embeded the Page Plugin in the right column:
https://trade.z.com/hk/tc/

It works perfectly in other browsers but not in Chrome.
Wait for a few mins and there will be an error prompted in the the developer tool's console.
Full error message as below:

Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/xti.php?xt=AZVp-LKocyBZqjT4dWwYI35ld4DtHr-18CJRT0Hkj94pDsEg0xQ6Huxs6yrp3fmq2cu7K5mYZ5FLGEpwTSBVR2q-ixCw8zf7TeQTEeE5mS3CUStk4vjo06NfLORxOEtFkK-ra_zb5E5lpxmLr6DyPkPd9KougTl8hhhe-Jv1AE1Zl-skzEHvVMRlJ6EoPH0UTSD23MhqQKSjL1R-egZRDSLD9FH3JR267SA7H9a5gZysuA8Daf999a4FP6WkyHYmQC8mtmMb_UMIeycl8qnakxN7vXZEK0xY8SI6dpDkgMDiZQyWpFatzx8ESy7b7eBRHJfam5Ru_AkgC7c4UeoE8dYlSyWtKDoTGyio2nH_02YMfd9OSPkBQZcjOhSCb1gLO9f9w07QxHK6q7pS6i3p2KS-UhfPncspgcQI-4k8qbQG-DZrZlHtGCXJloZB9hSwtZ68pTG8wtnCunKF5YSJuAZ5sAsFqYFsmkUrB-tExVIKTQJH413awON4bHNTcbHdx306leBNXemENdLL8QMkZPkAtVTYKKD3x7_Ii_dMwznfY2bb_0KFWGM--_ilgWJvx9ostH-iKsrGnbeToaodNu0cD9CI4wIGPtDkr47hSp7RDUaLMCIdzcMlnHjvPIajE4BcgGwo_LlNpxItVkStkA_cIEFbhEh4fHPk-Cka39TRVg&isv=1&cts=1512539623&csp' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Is there a way I can solve this error?
I tried to do edits on my website's Apache and it didn't work. 
Please help.

Comment: _“I tried to do edits on my website's Apache and it didn't work”_ - of course it didn’t, because your server has nothing to do with this. Facebook sends the header that disallows displaying this in frames on other domains. _“Is there a way I can solve this error?”_ - does it cause any _actual_ errors, impair the functionality of the plugin itself?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, CBroe.

Yes, I found that 'https://www.facebook.com/xti.php...' is kind of related to the video playing. Video can play in other broswers in the box but not in Chrome.

Comment: If you can set up an example that reliably reproduces the issue, then file a bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: Thanks for your help, CBroe.

It has been reported here:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/2002825156665478/

Answer (score 0):

It is also embeded the Pages below:
https://forex.z.com/hk/tc/
https://forex.z.com/hk/tc/whyzcomtrade/trustedtrading.html

There is a bug reported related to this issue in the developer support: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/2526305424326407/

Hope it will be resolved soon..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).